# How to write a curl with named multipart body

Tags: curl, multipart

I have a resource which accepts multipart files, it looks like this:

```
@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream
```

I want to write a curl to this resource, but I do not know how to name this parameter "file".

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-F` switch to send multipart. When you use this swtich at least one, the Content-Type will be automatically set to multipart/form-data. You can have more than one. For each one you can set a value of `<name>=<value>`. The `<value>` can be a file by using a `@` in front of the value. For instance `-F "file=@path_to_file"`. Here's from [the manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

> #### **`-F`**, **`--form <name=content>`**
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.
>
> Example: to send an image to a server, where 'profile' is the name of the form-field to which portrait.jpg will be the input:
>
> ```
> curl -F profile=@portrait.jpg https://example.com/upload.cgi
> ```
>
> To read content from stdin instead of a file, use - as the filename. This goes for both @ and < constructs. Unfortunately it does not support reading the file from a named pipe or similar, as it needs the full size before the transfer starts.
>
> You can also tell curl what Content-Type to use by using 'type=', in a manner similar to:
>
> ```
> curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" example.com
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> curl -F "name=daniel;type=text/foo" example.com
> ```
>
> You can also explicitly change the name field of a file upload part by setting filename=, like this:
>
> ```
> curl -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost" example.com
> ```
>
> If filename/path contains ',' or ';', it must be quoted by double-quotes like:
>
> ```
> curl -F "file=@\"localfile\";filename=\"nameinpost\"" example.com
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> curl -F 'file=@"localfile";filename="nameinpost"' example.com
> ```
>
> Note that if a filename/path is quoted by double-quotes, any double-quote or backslash within the filename must be escaped by backslash.
>
> See further examples and details in the MANUAL.
>
> This option can be used multiple times.

Comment: How do I supply the file content if I don't want to save it to disk and reference it using the `@` ?

Comment: @shleimel Just supply the JSON inline