# How to simulate multiple file upload with file name for each file by using Postman or Curl?

Tags: curl, django-rest-framework, postman, multipart, form-data

Requirement: Upload multiple files with custom file name for each file
Frontend: React

I use django rest api and want to get each file with associate data like custom file name. But I don't have idea to how to do this. When I receive api request with form-data that only contains files then it is okay to access these data using request.FILES/request.data. It is also okay to receive single file with its' file name because in form data we can set one key(file) for file and another key(text) for file name.

But how it is possible to use multiple files with file name for each file. Frontend is not designed/developed by me. So tried with curl/Postman to simulate the frontend request. But no idea about the real implementation of the backend and frontend. So no way to test this kind of request using Postman/Curl

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way: [How to write a curl with named multipart body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210093/how-to-write-a-curl-with-named-multipart-body)

Thanks to above question, I set file name with the file in curl request as below(added **filename** attribute). I could successfully simulate something I wanted. Still don't know that this will be compatible with frontend request.

```
curl --location --request POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/doc/" --form 'file=@"/media/Michel.pdf";filename="Mich"' --form 'file=@"/media/Hedra_Mel.pdf";filename="Mel"'
```